# Problem in connecting IBOutlet

Tags: iphone

In my application, I am trying to remove all existing subviews and add a new one created in Interface Builder. However, I don't seem to be able to connect the view.

When a button clicks, the following function is executed (inside a subclass of UIViewController):

```
// Display a list of settings to choose from
- (void) settings
{
    SettingsRootController *settingsController = [[SettingsRootController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"SettingsRootController" bundle:nil];
    _settingsController = settingsController;

    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) 
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:_settingsController.view2];

    int a = [self.view.subviews count];    
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

   ......
}


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SettingsRootController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIView *_view2;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *view2;
```

Inside the Interface Builder, I created a new View-based xib. Set file owner to SettingsRootController. Randomly drag a UITextView into the xib. Connect the UITextView to view and view2 in SettingsRootController.

However, if the above line is:

```
[self.view addSubview:_settingsController.view2];
```

a would always be 0, and thus the new screen is empty.

But if change to:

```
[self.view addSubview:_settingsController.view];
```

I could see the UITextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a view controller, its view will not be created at initialisation time. The view will be created at first access of the view property. Thats why it works when you use `_settingsController.view`. But when you access view2 the view will not be loaded. You could write a custom getter method like:

```
-(UIView*) view2 {
    _view2 = self.view;
    return _view2;
}
```

Comment: THis would only work if self.view is also connected. What if I haven't connected to view just my view2? I am trying this exercise because I have a complex xib which fails to connect to an IBOutlet in exactly the same way. So, I tried to reproduce the problem by trying a more simple UIView. Once I understand why I can't connect to view2, I will be to debug the complex xib.

Comment: You could create your view in code instead of loading from xib. All UI stuff loaded from xib will at first be available in the awakeFromNib-method. BTW, its more common to pass the data models to the view controllers and then configure the views in the controller itself (i.e. in viewDidLoad). You could also load your xib by hand - use loadNibNamed:owner:options: and extract your objects from the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

The instance var declaration is different from the property declaration! With and without underscore. Maybe thats why it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean? You mean _view2 and view2? I put @synthesize view2=_view2;

Comment: that seams ok, i'll write a new answer